# OSX Mavericks App Store won't connect as root

Tags: macos

Since Mavericks, I can no longer connect to the App Store.  I am using the root account and I do not want to create another user and go through setting everything up again.

Am I missing something or can you no longer use root for the app store?

Comment: What do you mean you are using the "root" account? There is no root user on OS X. Users can be administrators though.

Comment: @slhck Whilst it does seem unlikely to use the root account for day-to-day use, it is possible to have a root account in OS X…? ([Apple KB article: Enable and disable the root user](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11331))

Comment: @grgarside Yes, I know, I should have mentioned that there is no root user *by default*. The question is if the OP enabled it. I wouldn't be surprised if several things just don't work properly there.

Comment: Hmm, I thought Unix systems had a root account and OSX was based on FreeBSD. cat /etc/passwd | grep root root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, many sandboxed apps don't work right in root account, and Mavericks seems to have made some changes regarding this. The Mac App Store specifically seems to have trouble accessing certain files out of the range of normal sandbox, and shows the following error in Console:

```
kernel[0]: Sandbox: App Store(2054) deny file-write-data /private/var/db/mds/system/mds.lock
```

There does not appear to be a way round this, other than to use a user other than root.

Answer (score 1):

The root account has been increasingly limited by Apple Engineers.  Not sure whether this is by design or new coding has not been updated for the root user.  To answer you question, simply creating a new user and opening the App Store app via Terminal with that user's credentials will allow for the using of the app under the root user account.  There is no need to perform extensive setup for this secondary account. Additionally, other apps that have similar limits will benefit from this technique.

Here is a sample Terminal command:

```
sudo -u USER-SHORT-NAME-HERE \
        /Applications/App\ Store.app/Contents/MacOS/App\ Store &
```

The ampersand at the end of the command will allow the app of choice to run if you quit Terminal app.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by removing the lock file:

```
rm -f /private/var/db/mds/system/mds.lock
```

Comment: What are the side effects of removing that file?